# How to address endogeneity concerns using a recursive bivariate probit model?

Tags: r, econometrics, bivariate, endogeneity, recursive-model

I read a paper that addresses endogeneity concerns related to a binary moderator using recursive bivariate probit models.

Their approach is:

1. Analyze data using a recursive bivariate probit model.
2. Get separate coefficients when moderator = 0 vs moderator = 1.
3. Run a Chow test to compare the two cases.

I tried running a recursive bivariate probit model using the `endogeneity` package in R and also using the `rbiprobit` command in STATA.
I am not sure how to do Steps 2 and 3 above.
I get the first stage results and also the overall model coefficients. How can I get separate coefficients for the two cases of a moderator variable?

I tried the following simulation using sampleselection package but I am unable to recover the coefficients:

```
    library(MASS)
    library(mvtnorm)
    library(dplyr)
    library(sampleSelection)        
    vc <- diag(3)
    vc[lower.tri(vc)] <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.0)
    vc[upper.tri(vc)] <- vc[lower.tri(vc)]  ## First variance covariance matrix
    n <- 5000
    u <- rmvnorm(n, c(0,0,0), vc)
    
    run_simulation_1000 <- list()
    
    for (i in 1:1000) {
      swreg_data_df <- 
        data.frame(x1 = runif(n) - 0.50,
                   x2 = 2*runif(n) - 1.25,
                   x3 = runif(n) - 0.40,
                   z1 = runif(n) + 0.20,
                   z2 = runif(n) + 0.50) %>%
        mutate(u1 = u[,1],
               u2 = u[,2],
               u3 = u[,3]) %>%
        mutate(w_star = -3 + (1.0 * x1) + (0.8 * x2) - (0.5*z1) + (1.2*z2)  + u1,
               w = as.numeric(w_star > 0),
               y0s = (0.0 + 0.9*x1 + 0.2* u3)*(1-w),
               y1s = (-0.9 + 0.2*x1 + 0.5*x2 + 0.3* u2)*(w),
               y0 = as.numeric(y0s > 0),
               y1 = as.numeric(y1s > 0),
               y_star = y0s + y1s,
               y = as.numeric(y_star > 0))
      
      endoswtch <- selection(w ~ x1 + x2 + z1  , 
                             list(y ~ x1 + x2, 
                                  y ~ x1 + x2),
                             data = swreg_data_df,
                             method = "ml")
      
      get_intercepts <- data.frame(var_names = make.names(names(endoswtch[["estimate"]]), 
                                                          unique = TRUE),
                                   b_values = endoswtch[["estimate"]])
      
      run_simulation_1000[[i]] <- get_intercepts
      print(i)
    }
    
    all_1000_intercepts <- list()
    
    for(i in 1:1000){
      all_1000_intercepts[[i]] <- run_simulation_1000[[i]]$b_values
    }
    
    all_1000_intercepts_df <- do.call(rbind, all_1000_intercepts)
    all_1000_intercepts_df <- as.data.frame(all_1000_intercepts_df)
    
    library(ggplot2)
    library(tidyr)
    all_1000_intercepts_df %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
      filter(Variable %in% c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")) %>%
      ggplot() +
      aes(x = Value) +
      geom_density() +
      facet_wrap(~ Variable, scales = "free_x", nrow = 3)
```

I paraphrase the text from the published paper below:

> We confront a potential endogeneity problem: The existence of
> unobserved factors that are correlated with the moderator (business
> model) and with our outcome variable (probability of success).  We
> take several precautionary steps to account for the choice of business
> model.
>
> We control for the choice of business model by fitting a treatment
> effects model in which both the treatment and the outcome are binary,
> also known as a recursive bivariate probit model (Greene, 2018). This
> model is akin to the Heckman two-step control function, such that:

$$
\text{Outcome equation = } y_i = x_i \beta + w_i \delta + \epsilon_i, \\
\text{Treatment equation = } w^*_i = z_i \gamma + u_i, w_i = 1 
\text{ if } w^*_i > 0 \text{ and } w^*_i = 0 \text{ otherwise } \\
\text{Prob}(w_i = 1|z_i) = \Phi(z_i \gamma) \\
\\ \text{and} \\
\text{Prob}(w_i = 0|z_i) = 1 - \Phi(z_i \gamma)
$$

> Contrary to the Heckman two-step control function model, however, the
> outcome $y_i$ is observed for both $w_i=1$ (i.e., Business Model 1)
> and $w_i=0$ (i.e., Business Model 0). This allows us to conduct a Chow
> test on the independent variables and their interactions to assess
> their equality for two conditions. There need not be an exclusion
> restriction for recursive bivariate probit models to be identified.